# How to emit returned mongo query with socket.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

So what i'm trying to do is create a blog post and have that blog post update in realtime for all people viewing the blog. Now I have the basic app setup which allows me to list all posts, create a post, save it to mongo and have it update in realtime for the person creating the post. Standard SPA right!?

So I thought I could use socket.io to achieve the realtime update for all people viewing. I have managed to wire up socket.io to the point where all people viewing are updated in realtime but with the data from the submitted form, not the return results from mongo like with the person creating the post.

As a result the post updated to all people viewing is missing some data, such as a date created which is done by mongo.

This is the Admin Page, Form & NG-Repeat - I'm happy with this code

```
<div ng-controller="postsController" class="col-sm-8">
                <h3>Posts Controller</h3>

                <form ng-submit="addPost()">
                  <label>Title: </label><br /><input type="text" ng-model="post.title" autofocus required></input><br />
                  <label>By: </label><br /><input type="text" ng-model="post.by" required></input><br />
                  <label>Body: </label><div text-angular colorpicker ng-model="post.body" ></div><br />
                  <button type="submit">Post</button>
                </form>

                <br />

                <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-created_at' | limitTo: 1">
                    <div>
                        Title: {{ post.title }} <br />
                        Created: {{ post.created_at | date: 'MMM d, y' }} - By: {{ post.by }} <br /><br /> 
                        <div ta-bind ng-model="post.body">{{ post.body }}</div>
                    <hr />
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
```

This is the Blog Page

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:search | orderBy: 'created_at'">
                    <div>
                        Title: {{ post.title }} <br />
                        Created: {{ post.created_at | date: 'MMM d, y' }} - By: {{ post.by }} <br /><br /> 
                        <div ta-bind ng-model="post.body">{{ post.body }}     
                        </div>
                    <hr />
                    </div>
 </div>
```

This is the Angular postsController & socket.io listener

```
myApp.controller('postsController', ['$scope', '$location', 'postService', 'socketio', function($scope, $location, postService, socketio) {

$scope.posts = postService.querying();

socketio.on('post', function(msg) {
     //var msgPost = 
     $scope.posts.push(msg);
     console.log(msg);
     //console.log(msgPost);
});

$scope.addPost = function () {
        postService.create($scope.post)
          .$promise.then(
                function(result) {
                    $scope.posts = result; 
                    $scope.post = {};
                    console.log(result);
                }    
            );
};

}]);
```

This is the NodeJS postsController & socket.io emitter

```
var Post = require('../models/Posts');

module.exports.create = function (req, res) {
var post = new Post(req.body);
post.save(function (err) {

  Post.find({}, function (err, results) {
  res.json(results);
  io.emit('post', req.body);
  });

});

};
```

I can clearly see that i'm passing in the req.body to the io.emit but I can't figure out what I need to put in its place. I have tried several things but none have worked.

Thanks in advance.

Simon

Comment: Ok, so I think I may have solved this? Just testing now. Changed $scope.posts.push(msg); To $scope.posts = msg; And io.emit('post', req.body); To io.emit('post', results);

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm my previous comment and changes did indeed fix my mistakes.